# How do excitons move through a lattice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals

If an exciton is a photoexcited electron attracted to the hole in the valence shell it left behind, how does the quasiparticle move around? The hole isn't an actual particle. The hole is an effective +1 charge from the nucleus of the atom the electron was "liberated" from. How can this hole move?

Comment: While it may be a quasiparticle, it can and should be treated as a particle in pretty much every respect. It is an (empty) state in the band structure with all the rights and responsibilities accorded to a state.

Answer (score 0):

One can imagine well the motion of a quasiparticle in a crystal lattice from the [Ph.D. Thesis - Optical spectroscopy and hyloscopy of monolayers of tungsten disulphide](http://hdl.handle.net/1959.3/455711).

In a nutshell, exciton can be described by a joint wavefunction for electron and hole which would be delocalized over a number of unit cells. This delocalisation in combination with local fields assuming ideal crystal structure ultimately allows exciton to move around.